# Does the concept of user profiles exist in SonarQube?

Tags: concurrency, sonarqube, user-profile, sonarqube-scan

I am currently working with SonarQube v5.6.

I have a remote SonarQube server I would like to use as a "dev" box to which a number of developers can submit their code and have it analyzed. Is there an adverse impact on the dashboard if several developers execute the same project at the same time? Or does SonarQube allow for different "user profiles" in which the same project can be run? I would like to preserve the results of all executions and do not want one developer's execution to overwrite another's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What you asked for help doing**

Use the `sonar.branch` parameter and have each developer use a different value (maybe login name). That will keep them from overwriting each other on your "dev" box.

**What you *should* be doing instead**

Instead of maintaining a parallel "preview" box, you should be

1. having your developers use [SonarLint](http://www.sonarlint.org/) to see issues in their code as they type
2. using pull request analysis if your infrastructure allows ([Github](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin), [Bitbucket On Demand](https://github.com/mibexsoftware/sonar-bitbucket-plugin), [Bitbucket Server](https://github.com/AmadeusITGroup/sonar-stash))

Comment: Thank you, G. Ann. The `sonar.branch` parameter may be sufficient for our needs. Out of curiosity, is there any way to associate executions with users, such that when users log in, they see only their "instance" of the project and all the relevant analytics?

Comment: There is not @keharris

Comment: Understood. Thank you again for your help, G. Ann!